# ERROR 2018-09-21 10:48:12,022 instance.py:284] execve() arg 3 contains a non-string value?

Tags: gcloud

I'm facing the above error while running an application in google app engine. can anyone please clarify as to what this error means? and how to go about fixing this issue?